# Qual è il significato di "scolo" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Alessandro è tutto sommato un contemporaneo, un essere storico. Come superarà la gimcana del quotidiano, gli esami di maturità (ancora!), gli orecchioni, **lo scolo**, la droga, il rincoglionimento da televisione, la sua sterminata voglia di non fare un tubo?

Non riesco a immaginare quale possa essere il significato dello "scolo" in questo elenco di cose a superare da Alessandro, figlio di Vittorio Gassman. Ho letto tutte le [accezioni di questo vocabolo nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scolo/), ma nessuna sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Qualcuno di voi mi saprebbe spiegare cosa vuol dire "lo scolo" nel brano precedente?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Credo proprio che Gassman si riferisca alla gonorrea, la malattia venerea che viene (o veniva) appunto chiamata popolarmente “scolo” (vedi l'ultima accezione riportata dal Treccani), fra i possibili problemi grandi e piccoli che potrebbero colpire il figlio.

Comment: Decisamente la risposta corretta. *Scolo* è anche usato talvolta come termine per una generica malattia venerea (un po' come si dice *devo aver preso l'influenza* per dire che siamo malati di qualche malattia non specificata)